# length of string to include the length of a dict key

Tags: python, string, dictionary, string-length

How can I get the length of a string to include the length of the variable representing a key from a dict?

**Code**

```
def string_length(mystring):
    """ I am the doc string for this function"""
    length_of_string = len(mystring)
    print("mystring :   ",mystring)
    print("length of string : ", length_of_string)
    print('\n'*2)
    return length_of_string


def heading_from_string(mystring, symbol_string):
    los = string_length(mystring)
    print(symbol_string * los, '\n', mystring, '\n', symbol_string * los, sep = '')



a = {"imagefile1":2, "Image_file_2":3}


for k,v in a.items():
    print('\n'*2)
    mystring = ("testing_testing :", k)
    heading_from_string(mystring, "&")
```

**Return**

```
mystring :    ('testing_testing :', 'imagefile1')
length of string :  2



&&
('testing_testing :', 'imagefile1')
&&



mystring :    ('testing_testing :', 'Image_file_2')
length of string :  2



&&
('testing_testing :', 'Image_file_2')
&&
```

**Expected output**
The amount of symbols should be the same as the length of the text in mastering and the length of what is in the dict key k
e.g.

```
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
testing_testing :', 'imagefile1'
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `tuple` of length two with this line:

```
mystring = ("testing_testing :", k)
```

It should be:

```
mystring = "testing_testing :" + k
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a tuple, not a string. A simple solution can be to convert it to string, it this is what you want:

```
 heading_from_string(str(mystring), "&")
```

Or setting the string correctly:

```
 mystring = f"testing_testing : {k}"
```